# Is there a way to auto layout an image in a scroll view combined with page control?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uipagecontrol

This is my first entry. I am new in app designing and from Germany, but I still hope you can understand my problem. I used Xcode 11 and Swift 5.

I am using a page control and scroll view to switch between images in one screen. It looks good on the iPhone 11 but on the iPhone 8 the width and height of the images is too great, which is why part of the first image can still be seen when the page control is on the second segment. The same happens for the with the second image and the third segment.[This hopefully shows the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uATT3.jpg)
Is there a way to fit the images to the screen size?

This is my code:

````
```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var Pages: [String] = ["Page1","Page2","Page3"]
    var frame = CGRect.zero


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        pageControl.numberOfPages = Pages.count //
        setupScreens()
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func setupScreens() {
        for index in 0..<Pages.count {
            // 1.
            frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.size = scrollView.frame.size

            // 2.
            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: Pages[index])
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)        }

        // 3.
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(Pages.count)), height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.delegate = self


    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }

}

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally working fine except calling `setupScreens()` method in `viewDidLoad()`.

call that method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that it will get proper frame of `scrollView`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
          setupScreens()
}
```

Download demo from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_NgjUrZduwB4BMiF7dOkh-O-KlQU-2At)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was sitting on that problem for probably two hours.